# Find and Replace String between two values

Tags: java, regex

I want to find and replace values like:

```xml
<TAG>heading<foo></foo></TAG><foo>juergen</foo>
```

goal:

```xml
<TAG>heading</TAG><foo>juergen</foo>
```

I want to remove the `<foo>` Tags between `<TAG></TAG>`

Here is my attempt:

```java
replaceAll("</?foo\\b[^>]*>", "");
```

Comment: Nice attempt. What's going wrong?

Comment: all foo Tags are deleted. but i need only to delete the tags between <TAG></TAG>

Comment: Use an XML Parser for that problem. Regex is not the right tool for that job.

Comment: You aren't trying to [parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/712765), are you?

Comment: [Please stop generically whining about things that very often have a perfectly valid use case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/1729885). Parsing HTML with a regex is sometimes a good idea, sometimes not, stop trying to pass it off as evil by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String result = searchText.replaceAll("(<f.*><.*o>)(?=<)", "");
```

Comment: The javascript alternative `txt.replace(/(<f.*><.*o>)(?=<)/g,"")` doesn't seem to be removing anything: http://pastebin.com/N2EpQtJ9

Comment: @Mr.Russian it seems to not like this text: `<TAG>keep!<foo>throw</foo>keep!</TAG><foo>keep!</foo>`

Comment: @Isaac - your example is considerably more complex, but try this `searchText.replace(/(<f.*>.*<.*o>)(?=(.*(?=\<\/T.*)(?=\<\/)))/gm, "")`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `foo` is empty, you can use:

```
<([^/][^>]*)></\1>
```

This searches for an opening tag with an adjacent closing tag of the same name.

You could augment it to allow for whitespace in the middle with:

```
<([^/][^>]*)>\s*</\1>
```

Comment: Thankz for your reply, but it doesnt work. The name is <foo>. and i need only replace this name.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Otherwise, here is the regex, do not even ask me to explain, I barely know myself (this is in javascript, some corrections may need to be made for java):

```
var txt = "<TAG>a<foo>b</foo>c</TAG>d<foo>e</foo>f<TAG>g<foo>h</foo>i</TAG>j<TAG>k</TAG>";
var res = txt.replace(/(<TAG>.*?)<foo>.*?<\/foo>(.*?<\/TAG>)/gm,"$1$2");
//                     (   $1   )               (    $2    )
```